Best way to extract information from OUD logs in plain text format
I want to analyze logs from OUD (Oracle Unified Directory) and create some graphs using Kibana. I've installed a filebeat agent on the OUD server which ingests the logs and then sends them to elasticsearch. There aren't any preconfigured dashboard or module so I need to create everything from scratch. My problem is that the logs are in plain text format, all stored in one field "message". They can be of 5 types (BIND, CONNECT, SEARCH, DISCONNECT, UNBIND). Here are some examples :
[2024-06-19T16:00:00.479+02:00] [OUD] [TRACE] [OUD-24641548] [PROTOCOL] [host: XXXX.en] [nwaddr: X.X.X.X] [tid: 281] [userId: ouduser] [ecid: XXX,0:1] [category: REQ] [conn: 1694606] [op: 0] [msgID: 1] [bindType: SASL] [bindMech: DIGEST-MD5] [dn: ] BIND

[2024-06-19T16:00:00.489+02:00] [OUD] [TRACE] [OUD-24641551] [PROTOCOL] [host: XXXX.en] [nwaddr: X.X.X.X] [tid: 289] [userId: ouduser] [ecid: XXX,0:1] [category: REQ] [conn: -1] [op: 3105334] [msgID: 3105335] [base: XXX] [scope: base] [filter: (objectClass=*)] [attrs: ds-privilege-name,+,*] SEARCH

[2024-06-19T15:59:00.467+02:00] [OUD] [TRACE] [OUD-24641551] [PROTOCOL] [host: XXXX.en] [nwaddr: X.X.X.X] [tid: 281] [userId: ouduser] [ecid: XXX,0:1] [category: REQ] [conn: 1694593] [op: 4] [msgID: 5] [base: x] [scope: sub] [filter: (sAMAccountName=USER)] [attrs: dn,authPassword,orclPassword,orclguid] SEARCH

[2024-06-19T15:59:00.438+02:00] [OUD] [TRACE] [OUD-24641547] [PROTOCOL] [host: XXXX.en] [nwaddr: X.X.X.X] [tid: 105] [userId: ouduser] [ecid: XXX,0] [conn: 1694595] [reason: Client Disconnect] DISCONNECT

I try to use Grok to extract the fields but it it a nightmare as finding a pattern is impossible. Basically I want for each log something like this :
{
 type : BIND,
 timestamp : 2024-06-19T16:00:00.479+02:00,
 userId: ouduser,
 host: XXXX.en,
 //I want to be able to choose which field I include
 etc...
}


Is there a simple way to do that using Grok ?
If not, is there a tool I can use so that I don't need to give the exact pattern expected for the log (because in my case it's impossible even between same type of log)

Thanks for your help !

Tldr;
Grok or Dissect are going to be your go to tools for that.
Since elastic does not seems to have an integration for OUD, I believe you will have to parse it yourself.
Boiler plate
Please find below some boiler plate code I wrote using:

Your input
Kibana > Dev Tools > Grok debugger

 input {
      generator {
        lines => [
          "[2024-06-19T16:00:00.479+02:00] [OUD] [TRACE] [OUD-24641548] [PROTOCOL] [host: XXXX.en] [nwaddr: X.X.X.X] [tid: 281] [userId: ouduser] [ecid: XXX,0:1] [category: REQ] [conn: 1694606] [op: 0] [msgID: 1] [bindType: SASL] [bindMech: DIGEST-MD5] [dn: ] BIND",
          "[2024-06-19T16:00:00.489+02:00] [OUD] [TRACE] [OUD-24641551] [PROTOCOL] [host: XXXX.en] [nwaddr: X.X.X.X] [tid: 289] [userId: ouduser] [ecid: XXX,0:1] [category: REQ] [conn: -1] [op: 3105334] [msgID: 3105335] [base: XXX] [scope: base] [filter: (objectClass=*)] [attrs: ds-privilege-name,+,*] SEARCH",
          "[2024-06-19T15:59:00.467+02:00] [OUD] [TRACE] [OUD-24641551] [PROTOCOL] [host: XXXX.en] [nwaddr: X.X.X.X] [tid: 281] [userId: ouduser] [ecid: XXX,0:1] [category: REQ] [conn: 1694593] [op: 4] [msgID: 5] [base: x] [scope: sub] [filter: (sAMAccountName=USER)] [attrs: dn,authPassword,orclPassword,orclguid] SEARCH",
          "[2024-06-19T15:59:00.438+02:00] [OUD] [TRACE] [OUD-24641547] [PROTOCOL] [host: XXXX.en] [nwaddr: X.X.X.X] [tid: 105] [userId: ouduser] [ecid: XXX,0] [conn: 1694595] [reason: Client Disconnect] DISCONNECT"
        ]
        count => 1
      }
    }

filter { 
  grok {
    match => {
      "message" => [
        "\[%{DATA:@timestamp}\] \[%{WORD:service.name}\] \[%{WORD:log.level}\] \[%{DATA:service.id}\] \[%{DATA:unknw}\] \[host:%{DATA:host.domain}\] \[nwaddr:%{DATA:host.ip}\] \[tid:%{DATA:process.thread.id}\] \[userId:%{DATA:user.id}\] \[ecid:%{DATA:transaction.id}\] \[category:%{DATA:event.category}\] \[conn:%{DATA:network.connection.id}\] \[op:%{DATA:operation.id}\] \[msgID:%{DATA:event.id}\] \[bindType:%{DATA:auth.type}\] \[bindMech:%{DATA:auth.mech}\] \[dn:%{DATA:dn}\] %{WORD:event.action}",
        "\[%{DATA:@timestamp}\] \[%{WORD:service.name}\] \[%{WORD:log.level}\] \[%{DATA:service.id}\] \[%{DATA:unknw}\] \[host:%{DATA:host.domain}\] \[nwaddr:%{DATA:host.ip}\] \[tid:%{DATA:process.thread.id}\] \[userId:%{DATA:user.id}\] \[ecid:%{DATA:transaction.id}\] \[category:%{DATA:event.category}\] \[conn:%{DATA:network.connection.id}\] \[op:%{DATA:operation.id}\] \[msgID:%{DATA:event.id}\] \[base:%{DATA:base}\] \[scope:%{DATA:scope}\] \[filter:%{DATA:filter}\] \[attrs:%{DATA:attrs}\] %{WORD:event.action}",
        "\[%{DATA:@timestamp}\] \[%{WORD:service.name}\] \[%{WORD:log.level}\] \[%{DATA:service.id}\] \[%{DATA:unknw}\] \[host:%{DATA:host.domain}\] \[nwaddr:%{DATA:host.ip}\] \[tid:%{DATA:process.thread.id}\] \[userId:%{DATA:user.id}\] \[ecid:%{DATA:transaction.id}\] \[conn:%{DATA:network.connection.id}\] \[reason:%{DATA:reason}\] %{WORD:event.action}"
      ]
    }
  }
}

output { 
  stdout { codec =>  "rubydebug" } 
}


Solution in TXR.
First, let us get the data out. In xtract.txr we have this prototype code:
@(repeat)
[@timestamp] @(coll :vars (prop value))@\
                @(cases)@\
                   [@{prop /[^\]:]+/}: @value]@\
                @(or)@\
                   [@prop]@(bind value nil)@\
                @(or)@\
                  @{token /\S+/}@(bind (prop value) (:type token))@\
                @(end)@\
             @(end)
@  (do (prinl (zip prop value)))
@(end)

which gets us:
$ txr xform.txr log
(("OUD" nil) ("TRACE" nil) ("OUD-24641548" nil) ("PROTOCOL" nil)
 ("host" "XXXX.en") ("nwaddr" "X.X.X.X") ("tid" "281") ("userId" "ouduser")
 ("ecid" "XXX,0:1") ("category" "REQ") ("conn" "1694606") ("op" "0")
 ("msgID" "1") ("bindType" "SASL") ("bindMech" "DIGEST-MD5") ("dn" "")
 (:type "BIND"))
(("OUD" nil) ("TRACE" nil) ("OUD-24641551" nil) ("PROTOCOL" nil)
 ("host" "XXXX.en") ("nwaddr" "X.X.X.X") ("tid" "289") ("userId" "ouduser")
 ("ecid" "XXX,0:1") ("category" "REQ") ("conn" "-1") ("op" "3105334")
 ("msgID" "3105335") ("base" "XXX") ("scope" "base") ("filter" "(objectClass=*)")
 ("attrs" "ds-privilege-name,+,*") (:type "SEARCH"))
(("OUD" nil) ("TRACE" nil) ("OUD-24641551" nil) ("PROTOCOL" nil)
 ("host" "XXXX.en") ("nwaddr" "X.X.X.X") ("tid" "281") ("userId" "ouduser")
 ("ecid" "XXX,0:1") ("category" "REQ") ("conn" "1694593") ("op" "4")
 ("msgID" "5") ("base" "x") ("scope" "sub") ("filter" "(sAMAccountName=USER)")
 ("attrs" "dn,authPassword,orclPassword,orclguid") (:type "SEARCH"))
(("OUD" nil) ("TRACE" nil) ("OUD-24641547" nil) ("PROTOCOL" nil)
 ("host" "XXXX.en") ("nwaddr" "X.X.X.X") ("tid" "105") ("userId" "ouduser")
 ("ecid" "XXX,0") ("conn" "1694595") ("reason" "Client Disconnect")
 (:type "DISCONNECT"))

We have the stuff as Lisp data, keyword value pairs.

Entries like [foo: ] have key "foo" and value "" (empty string).

Entries like [foo] have key "foo" and value nil.

Entries like foo have key :type and value "foo".


The :type entry occurs only once in each record, as we want.
Now the job is just to massage the data into the desired output form. It will behoove us to throw the data into a hash table:
$ txr xform.txr log
{
  type : BIND,
  timestamp : 2024-06-19T16:00:00.479+02:00,
  userId: ouduser,
  host : XXXX.en,
  category : REQ
}
{
  type : SEARCH,
  timestamp : 2024-06-19T16:00:00.489+02:00,
  userId: ouduser,
  host : XXXX.en,
  category : REQ
}
{
  type : SEARCH,
  timestamp : 2024-06-19T15:59:00.467+02:00,
  userId: ouduser,
  host : XXXX.en,
  category : REQ
}
{
  type : DISCONNECT,
  timestamp : 2024-06-19T15:59:00.438+02:00,
  userId: ouduser,
  host : XXXX.en,
}

Updated code:
@(repeat)
[@timestamp] @(coll :vars (prop value))@\
                @(cases)@\
                   [@{prop /[^\]:]+/}: @value]@\
                @(or)@\
                   [@prop]@(bind value nil)@\
                @(or)@\
                  @{token /\S+/}@(bind (prop value) (:type token))@\
                @(end)@\
             @(end)
@  (bind h @(hash-from-pairs (zip prop value)))
@  (output)
{
  type : @[h :type],
  timestamp : @timestamp,
  userId: @[h "userId"],
  host : @[h "host"],
@    (if [h "category"])
  category : @[h "category"]
@    (end)
}
@  (end)
@(end)

In color:

